# How to center text vertically in a table cell?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I designed this table for my presentation, but in some cells the text is aligned at the top and ooks bad. 
I want the text to be centered vertically but I do not know how.
Thanks for the help.

MY code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %%para que salga la tilde en el idioma español
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Drogas antituberculosas.}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{6cm}|}
\hline
% after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
Tipo & Grupo & Fármacos \\
\hline
 Primera Línea & Grupo 1: Agentes de primera línea & Isoniacida (H), rifampicina (R), etambutol (E), pirazinamida (Z), estreptomicina (S). \\
 \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Segunda Línea} & Grupo 2: Agentes inyectables & Kanamicina (Km), amikacina (Am), capreomicina (Cm). \\
\cline{2-3}
& Grupo 3:Fluoroquinolonas & levofloxacina (Lfx), moxifloxacina (Mfx) \\
\cline{2-3}
& Grupo 4: Agentes bacteriostáticos orales & etionamida (Eto), cicloserina (Cs), ácido para-amino salicílico (PAS) \\
\cline{2-3}
 & Grupo 5: Agentes con evidencia limitada & clofazimina (Cfz), linezolid (Lzd), amoxicilina/ clavulánico(Amx/Clv), meropenem (Mpm),imipenem/ cilastatina (Ipm/Cln), dosis altas de isoniacida, claritromicina (Clr), tioridazina (Tio) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: my table]

Comment: instead `p{...}` for column type use `m{...}`. for it you should load package `array`. in your preamble also missing `multirow`package ... welcome to tex.se!

Comment: for centering content of `multirow` cell use `\multirow{12}{*}{Segunda Línea} `, i.e. it span 12 lines ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aligned to the top looks bad? hm, matter of personal taste :)

please compare tables generated by the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %%para que salga la tilde en el idioma español
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, multirow}    % for the first table
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}  % for the second table
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Drogas antituberculosas. (according to your taste)}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|>{\RaggedRight}m{6.3cm}|}
\hline
% after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
Tipo            & Grupo     & Fármacos \\
    \hline
Primera Línea   & Grupo 1: Agentes de primera línea & Isoniacida (H), rifampicina (R), etambutol (E), pirazinamida (Z), estreptomicina (S). \\
    \hline
\multirow{12}{*}{Segunda Línea}
                & Grupo 2: Agentes inyectables & Kanamicina (Km), amikacina (Am), capreomicina (Cm). \\
\cline{2-3}
& Grupo 3:Fluoroquinolonas & levofloxacina (Lfx), moxifloxacina (Mfx) \\
\cline{2-3}
& Grupo 4: Agentes bacteriostáticos orales & etionamida (Eto), cicloserina (Cs), ácido para-amino salicílico (PAS) \\
\cline{2-3}
 & Grupo 5: Agentes con evidencia limitada & clofazimina (Cfz), linezolid (Lzd), amoxicilina/ clavulánico(Amx/Clv), meropenem (Mpm),imipenem/ cilastatina (Ipm/Cln), dosis altas de isoniacida, claritromicina (Clr), tioridazina (Tio) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}


    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Drogas antituberculosas. (according to my taste)}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c >{\hsize=0.65\hsize}R >{\hsize=1.35\hsize}R @{}}
    \toprule
Tipo            & Grupo     & Fármacos \\
    \midrule
Primera Línea   & Grupo 1: Agentes de primera línea
                            & Isoniacida (H), rifampicina (R), etambutol (E), pirazinamida (Z), estreptomicina (S). \\
    \midrule
Segunda Línea   & Grupo 2: Agentes inyectables
                            & Kanamicina (Km), amikacina (Am), capreomicina (Cm). \\
    \addlinespace
                & Grupo 3:Fluoroquinolonas
                            & levofloxacina (Lfx), moxifloxacina (Mfx) \\
    \addlinespace
                & Grupo 4: Agentes bacteriostáticos orales
                            & etionamida (Eto), cicloserina (Cs), ácido para-amino salicílico (PAS) \\
    \addlinespace
            & Grupo 5: Agentes con evidencia limitada
                            & clofazimina (Cfz), linezolid (Lzd), amoxicilina/ clavulánico(Amx/Clv), meropenem (Mpm),imipenem/ cilastatina (Ipm/Cln), dosis altas de isoniacida, claritromicina (Clr), tioridazina (Tio) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: good :), than first part of my mwe solve your problem. now you can accept my answer by clicking on check mark on the top left side of it. happy tex-ing!